# CSS スライドショーを完成させたい。

Tags: html, css

[動くCSSのためのメモスライドショー](https://lopan.jp/css-animation-slideshow/)を参考にして、スライドショーを作成しました。
動くようになったのですが、もう少し手を加えたくて投稿しました。

やりたいこと

・次の画像に遷移するためのボタンを透明化して、画像を両サイドいっぱいにしたい。
　-今はlightSeaGreenが設定されているので、そこを透明にするのはできるのですが、画像が思うように両サイドいっぱいにならないで困ってます。
・高さをもう少し短くしたい。どの部分を変更すれば高さの調節ができますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

```css
@charset "utf-8";

.slideshow {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
input[name="slideshow"] {
display: none;
}

/* :::::: slideContents :::::: */
.slideContents {
position: relative;
background: lightSeaGreen;
text-align: center;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
transition: transform .6s;
}
.slideContents section {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
transform: translateX(100%);
transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
.slideContents section img {
max-width: 100%;
padding: 0 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
vertical-align: middle;
}

/* :::::: arrows :::::: */
.arrow,
.arrow label,
.arrow .ico {
position: absolute;
}
.arrow {
top: 0;
margin: 0;
transition: background .3s;
}
.prev {
left: 0;
}
.next {
right: 0;
}
.arrow:hover {
background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.arrow,
.arrow label {
cursor: pointer;
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
}
.arrow label {
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
.arrow .ico {
top: calc(50% - 6px);
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
border-top: 3px solid #fff;
opacity: 0;
}
.prev .ico {
left: 50%;
border-left: 3px solid #fff;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
transition: left .3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1), opacity .3s;
}
.next .ico {
right: 50%;
border-right: 3px solid #fff;
transform: rotate(45deg);
transition: right .3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1), opacity .3s;
}
.arrow:hover .ico {
opacity: .6;
}
.prev:hover .ico {
left: calc(50% - 6px);
}
.next:hover .ico {
right: calc(50% - 6px);
}

/* :::::: mechanism :::::: */
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5 {
position: relative;
transform: none;
}
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3 {
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3,
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3 {
transition-duration: 0s;
}

/* :::::: arrow mechanism :::::: */
.arrow label {
pointer-events: none;
}
#switch1:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch5"],
#switch2:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch1"],
#switch3:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch2"],
#switch4:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch3"],
#switch5:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch4"],
#switch1:checked ~ .next label[for="switch2"],
#switch2:checked ~ .next label[for="switch3"],
#switch3:checked ~ .next label[for="switch4"],
#switch4:checked ~ .next label[for="switch5"],
#switch5:checked ~ .next label[for="switch1"] {
pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<div class="slideshow">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch2">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch3">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch4">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch5">
<div class="slideContents">
    <section id="slide1">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/24/10/23/pier-5086290_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide2">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/02/07/51/luka-5249892_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide3">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/13/17/16/netherlands-5039354_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide4">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/15/12/09/summer-5046401_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide5">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/11/20/35/lighthouse-5031977_1280.jpg">
    </section>
</div>
<p class="arrow prev">
    <i class="ico"></i>
    <label for="switch1"></label>
    <label for="switch2"></label>
    <label for="switch3"></label>
    <label for="switch4"></label>
    <label for="switch5"></label>
</p>
<p class="arrow next">
    <i class="ico"></i>
    <label for="switch1"></label>
    <label for="switch2"></label>
    <label for="switch3"></label>
    <label for="switch4"></label>
    <label for="switch5"></label>
</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 今はlightSeaGreenが設定されているので、そこを透明にするのはできるのですが、画像が思うように両サイドいっぱいにならないで困ってます。

imgにpaddingがついてますね。こちらを外せば問題ないかと

> ・高さをもう少し短くしたい。どの部分を変更すれば高さの調節ができますでしょうか。

slideContents に高さを設定すればよろしいと思います。

CSSの調整についてですが
CSSを試すにはChromeのF12のElementsタブでStyleなどを利用してCSSを動的にいじるとわかりやすいと思います。直接スタイルを変更したり、paddingをなくしたりといった操作が動的に対応ができます。
一度お試しを。

```css
@charset "utf-8";

.slideshow {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
input[name="slideshow"] {
display: none;
}

/* :::::: slideContents :::::: */
.slideContents {
position: relative;
background: lightSeaGreen;
text-align: center;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
transition: transform .6s;
height: 200px;
}
.slideContents section {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
transform: translateX(100%);
transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
.slideContents section img {
max-width: 100%;
padding: 0 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
vertical-align: middle;
height: -webkit-fill-available;
width: fit-content;
}

/* :::::: arrows :::::: */
.arrow,
.arrow label,
.arrow .ico {
position: absolute;
}
.arrow {
top: 0;
margin: 0;
transition: background .3s;
}
.prev {
left: 0;
}
.next {
right: 0;
}
.arrow:hover {
background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.arrow,
.arrow label {
cursor: pointer;
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
}
.arrow label {
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
.arrow .ico {
top: calc(50% - 6px);
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
border-top: 3px solid #fff;
opacity: 0;
}
.prev .ico {
left: 50%;
border-left: 3px solid #fff;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
transition: left .3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1), opacity .3s;
}
.next .ico {
right: 50%;
border-right: 3px solid #fff;
transform: rotate(45deg);
transition: right .3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1), opacity .3s;
}
.arrow:hover .ico {
opacity: .6;
}
.prev:hover .ico {
left: calc(50% - 6px);
}
.next:hover .ico {
right: calc(50% - 6px);
}

/* :::::: mechanism :::::: */
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5 {
position: relative;
transform: none;
}
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3 {
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3,
#switch1:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide4,
#switch2:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide5,
#switch3:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide1,
#switch4:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide2,
#switch5:checked ~ .slideContents #slide3 {
transition-duration: 0s;
}

/* :::::: arrow mechanism :::::: */
.arrow label {
pointer-events: none;
}
#switch1:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch5"],
#switch2:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch1"],
#switch3:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch2"],
#switch4:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch3"],
#switch5:checked ~ .prev label[for="switch4"],
#switch1:checked ~ .next label[for="switch2"],
#switch2:checked ~ .next label[for="switch3"],
#switch3:checked ~ .next label[for="switch4"],
#switch4:checked ~ .next label[for="switch5"],
#switch5:checked ~ .next label[for="switch1"] {
pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<div class="slideshow">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch2">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch3">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch4">
<input type="radio" name="slideshow" id="switch5">
<div class="slideContents">
    <section id="slide1">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/24/10/23/pier-5086290_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide2">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/02/07/51/luka-5249892_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide3">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/13/17/16/netherlands-5039354_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide4">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/15/12/09/summer-5046401_1280.jpg">
    </section>
    <section id="slide5">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/11/20/35/lighthouse-5031977_1280.jpg">
    </section>
</div>
<p class="arrow prev">
    <i class="ico"></i>
    <label for="switch1"></label>
    <label for="switch2"></label>
    <label for="switch3"></label>
    <label for="switch4"></label>
    <label for="switch5"></label>
</p>
<p class="arrow next">
    <i class="ico"></i>
    <label for="switch1"></label>
    <label for="switch2"></label>
    <label for="switch3"></label>
    <label for="switch4"></label>
    <label for="switch5"></label>
</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。思い通りできました。高さを変えたところ、少し画像が切れてしまったのですが、指定の高さで画像を全体表示させるのは難しいのでしょうか。。？

Comment: 画像自体の縦幅横幅を変えたい場合は`.slideContents section img`のスタイルを調整してみてください。ただそうすると、比率によっては背景が出てきたりしてしまいますので、`.slideContents`と調整をしてみてください。

Comment: やってみます！ありがとうございました。

Comment: 先ほどのアドバイスを頂いて、やってみましたが、hightを400に設定して.slideContents section img にbackground-size coverを追加したら、pcではうまくいったのですが、携帯のデバイスで確認したら写真のしたに余白が出てきてしまいます。携帯でも余白が出ずに指定した高さで写真を一面に出すようにするにはどのようなどのような方法が適切でしょうか。重ね重ねの質問で申し訳ないですが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `background-size cover`はコンテンツ高さを設定するものではなく、背景画像のコンテンツとのフィット具合を調整するものです。imgをheightを400にするなどしてみてください。ちなみに回答のほうは`-webkit-fill-available`や`fit-content;`を利用して調整しています

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。色々とやってみましたが、できませんでした。。別の質問を出しますので、よかったらお力添えいただければと思います。